# Macro's depth in C

Tags: c, string, macros

Is there a limit to macro's depth in C?

I wrote a macro to stringify n macro arguments by calling a `string##n` macro. However, when I try to use it in another macro it seems to not evaluate propery.

E.g.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define NARGS(ARGS...) NARGS_HELPER1(ARGS, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define NARGS_HELPER1(ARGS...) NARGS_HELPER2(ARGS)
#define NARGS_HELPER2(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, N, ...) N

#define STRINGIFY(N, ARGS...) STRING##N(ARGS)
#define STRING1(X1) {#X1}
#define STRING2(X1, X2) {#X1, #X2}
#define STRING3(X1, X2, X3) {#X1, #X2, #X3}
#define STRING4(X1, X2, X3, X4) {#X1, #X2, #X3, #X4}
#define STRING5(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) {#X1, #X2, #X3, #X4, #X5}
#define STRING6(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6) {#X1, #X2, #X3, #X4, #X5, #X6}
#define STRING7(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7) {#X1, #X2, #X3, #X4, #X5, #X6, #X7}
#define STRING8(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8) {#X1, #X2, #X3, #X4, #X5, #X6, #X7, #X8}
#define STRING9(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9) {#X1, #X2, #X3, #X4, #X5, #X6, #X7, #X8, #X9}

#define CLOSURE(NAME, ARGS...)                                                 \
const uint8_t NAME##_args_n = NARGS(ARGS);                                     \
const char *NAME##_args_types[NARGS(ARGS)] = STRINGIFY(NARGS(ARGS), ARGS)

CLOSURE(func, int, float, char);
```

Upon calling the `CLOSURE` macro I get some garbage value at `STRINGIFY` evaluation:

```
const uint8_t func_args_n = 3;
const char *func_args_types[3] = STRINGNARGS(int, float, char)(int, float, char);
```

Also interesting to me is why parenthesis around `ARGS` vanish, and why arguments appear to be duplicated?

Comment: VLA at file scope is invalid C. Are these declarations inside a function?

Comment: @Harith The code as-is doesn't compile because it is invalid C...

Comment: Yes, indeed. `macros.c: In function ‘main’:

macros.c:24:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

   24 |     CLOSURE(func, int, float, char);`

Comment: Try `#define concat(a,b) a##b` and `#define STRINGIFY(N, ARGS...) concat(STRING,N)(ARGS)`

Comment: Thank you @chqrlie. Please make it in to an answer so I can accept you commission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a limit to macro's depth in C?

There are implementation limits in C preprocessor implementations, and there are constraints specified in the C Standard, but these are not causing your problem.

The problem is in the macro `#define STRINGIFY(N, ARGS...) STRING##N(ARGS)`:

For the token sequence substituted for `N` to be expanded before token pasting is applied by `##`, you must use an intermediary macro and pass `STRING` and `N` as macro arguments:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define STRINGIFY(N, ARGS...) CONCAT(STRING,N)(ARGS)
```

This might not suffice for your goal but should help achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the initial question: no, the C Standard does not specify a limit on the macro depth understood as the maximal number of recursive macro expansions necessary to expand a given macro.

The standard (C17, 5.2.4.1), however, does specify some other interesting limits regarding macros including the following:

- 4095 macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one preprocessing
  translation unit
- 127 parameters in one macro definition
- 127 arguments in one macro invocation

These are minimum limits and implementations may very well provide higher limits or no fixed limits at all (which is encouraged by a footnote in the Standard). However, when writing portable code, this should be kept in mind. It may be difficult to ensure that the limit on the number of macro identifiers is kept since inclusion of standard headers is likely to define a number of macros which is not under control of the application code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's build this up a piece at a time:

```
#define CLOSURE(NAME, ARGS...) STRINGIFY(NARGS(ARGS), ARGS)

CLOSURE(func, int, float, char);
```

Using `gcc -E`, we see that this expands to:

```
STRINGIFY(NARGS(int, float, char), int, float, char);
```

---

Next, `STRINGIFY()` is expanded, so add that definition and run `gcc -E` again:

```
#define CLOSURE(NAME, ARGS...) STRINGIFY(NARGS(ARGS), ARGS)
#define STRINGIFY(N, ARGS...) STRING##N(ARGS)

CLOSURE(func, int, float, char);
```

In this expansion, `N` is `NARGS(int, float, char)` and `ARGS` is `int, float, char`, so we get:

```
STRINGNARGS(int, float, char)(int, float, char);
```

---

There are no further defined macros to expand, so that's the final result.

Comment: No, `NARGS` is a macro which is clearly defined above. `STRINGIFY` macro works with no flows

Comment: @siery Macro expansion doesn't work that way. This is the only answer that answers your last question("why arguments appear to be duplicated"). Although it did not provide a solution like `@chqrlie's answer, I don't see anything factually wrong in this answer.

Comment: @siery, I'm not sure what you mean by "no".  Try it for yourself.

Comment: This answer tells only what the macro evaluatest to, it's pretty self explanatory. It also completely ignores the question included in the title. Really this answer looks like something generate by AI as it exceptionally misses the point.

Comment: @siery, if you read the question it claims that the macro expands to "_some garbage value_", which implies that the asker doesn't understand how the expansion works (otherwise this result would have been expected).  This is the requested step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Yes, and @chqrlie has explained why this garbage value occurs. I can trace the macro evaluation to this point, but this solely does not help me solve the problem.

Comment: It's not _garbage_ - it's exactly what the macro expands to.  There's nothing going wrong here.

Comment: And this assumption is evident in your answer. In this macro `ARGN` is not evaluated before token pasting is applied by `##` and this is wrong.

Comment: No, it's _not_ wrong - that's exactly how it's specified to work.

Comment: Like literaly every wrong code ever written.

Comment: You try to make it sound like I talked about the language implementation being wrong but there is no reason to make such assumption.

Comment: You specifically said "_`ARGN` is not evaluated before token pasting is applied by `##` and this is wrong_".  If you were expecting `ARGN()` to be expanded before `##` joins the tokens, then it's _that expectation_ that's wrong, not your compiler.

Comment: It makes me happy that you've figured this out.